# Jenkins rebuild not loading choice parameters values

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

We have jobs with choice parameters (Single select).
When I rebuild a job (Using rebuilder plugin), the choice parameter appears as a String parameters with the value of the last run and we don't have the option to choose another value (Only write it down).
Is there any option to make the rebuild load the choices options so we will be able to select another value and not write it down?

Thanks.

Couldn't find any open issue regarding this bug, looking forward for some help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with Jenkins Rebuilder plugin.
You can find the issue tracker here: Jenkins Rebuilder Plugin issue tracker:  https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-67959